# App created in Corona stuck loading: Only Mac/ iOS devices

Tags: ios, lua, loading, coronasdk

I'm currently working on a game designed for iOS devices, using corona. The game works fine on pc, it loads up the menu fine and all levels work (this is with using corona). When I run the game on a device/x code simulator/ or even corona itself it has a problem loading. The menu works perfectly fine, however once i click 'play' - the level is loaded up but I'm met with a the default iOS loading icon (circular thingy). The level can be seen, it's just dimmed because of the loading screen. I can't do anything and I've tried to see if the game will eventually load, but it never does.

So in short, i'm stuck loading the level.

I've looked around for an answer but found nothing. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you reproduce this situation with a minimal amount of code?

Comment: No idea how i would recreate this. Makes it more harder because no one else seems to be having this problems

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is something like the android debug bridge for iOS.
If so, try to print statements to the debug console at different positions of your code. so you can find the function that causes the problem (the one that no more prints a statement ;). And than you have to see if in this function there is something that is not device compatible.

Sorry that I can not be more specific, I dont have iOS experience, but this is the way I do it with android. And it happend many times that my code runs perfectly in the simulator but not on the device.

Hope this helps a little,
cheers, felix

Answer (score 0):

There may be messages in the console log.  This tutorial will help you find your console log and find errors in it:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/

You may also need to put in some print statements (that will show in the log) and try to narrow down where you are beachballing/pinwheeling and see what the cause is.